# Flying Turkish Airlines, what are credit card rules?

Tags: air-travel, turkish-airlines, payment-verifications

I have return tickets flying out of SFO on Turkish airlines for the whole family. The credit card I used to book the tickets has since been replaced by the bank with a new card.

In order to board, can I present the new credit card (same name) at the checkin counter, or must I present the original credit card (which is no longer valid and has been discarded)?

By 'discarded' - I mean cut up and thrown away in trash. It was no longer valid, since it was replaced with a new card. So can I use the new card to travel on a booking that was made using the original card?

The new card has a new number; and the ticket was purchased through an agent.

Comment: @m.jam ... are you the same as mj111 and were trying to add content to your own question, that the card number is different and that the tix were purchased through a travel agent? If so, better to add that to the original question, which will improve the answers.

Answer (score 6):

If you bought your tickets directly with Turkish, then things should be [clear](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/legal-notice/terms-amp-conditions/ticketing-service-payment)

> **Presentation of Credit Card:** If our system detects risks regarding the transaction, you will need to present your credit card for the tickets purchased via our web site and mobil application before the flight. The system asks for your approval concerning the presentation of your credit card if risks are detected regarding the transaction. (“You will be requested to present your credit card before the flight. Do you approve of this request?”).

and

> **Situations That Do Not Require Presentation of Credit Card:** If you did not encounter any prompts regarding the presentation of your credit card during your transaction, you will not be requested to present your credit card. This procedure will also not be necessary for tickets purchased with 3D Secure approval.

Also have a look [here](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/corporate/customer-contact-center/ask-us/website-and-online-transactions) regarding this.

If however you bought your tickets through a third party (say expedia), then I don't know how this is being handled. There are [reports of denied boarding](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293969-i367-k6157477-Turkish_Airlines_and_credit_card_issue_HELP-Turkey.html) for failure to present the card.

Turkish does mention the [CC requirement for Online-Checkin](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/frequently-asked-questions/travel-information/online-check-in)

> Passenger who paid the ticket by credit card should keep their ID and also the related credit card to show it out to the boarding agent.

while no such thing is mentioned for [checking in at the counter](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/frequently-asked-questions/travel-information/check-in-information) - however that means nothing given the above.

To be on the safe side, see if you can obtain a copy of the old card, a statement from the bank or anything that proves you have been the rightful holder of said card. Also your new card might have the same number and be useful. If you want to make even more sure, contact TK customer service, e.g. via twitter and ask if you can give them your booking number to check whether the CC is required.

Comment: If the ticket is bought through an agent, then the operating airline doesn't care, because the agent is liable for the card fraud, not the airline. Indeed the airline may not even receive details about the card that was used to make the transaction.

Comment: As @mts has pointed out, the card most likely has the same number, just a new expiration date, which is most common when a US bank-issued card is replaced (and you're instructed to cut up the old one). It's when a card has been lost or stolen that the replacement generally has a new number. You can easily verify by making a call to the toll free number on the card's reverse, or by logging into your account on your bank's online system.

Comment: With the detail you've added and, again as @mts suggests, your credit card statement which shows the processing of the payment for the tickets, and which will include a very long alpha-numeric authorization code should be sufficient. Take the full statement, not just the page on which the charge appears, as it will have all of your identifying info.