# Credit card lost after booking the flight with it

Tags: airlines, payment-cards

I recently booked online tickets for a flight from Delhi to Paro on the 10th February 2017. A few days ago, I lost the credit card I used. As per the guidelines, I have to have my credit card I used at the time of boarding.

I did block my card by calling my bank, and requested a replacement. The new card will have a new number BUT same CNR number (customer relation number).

Will this be a problem? I did email the airline but, so far no reply.

Comment: Did the airline specifically told you that showing card will be required during booking? Did you use 3D Secure confirmation during payment?

Comment: Did you submit the CRN as part of the payment data when you submitted the booking?  If not how will the airline know the CRN is the same?

Comment: i tried calling the airline helpline but they said they have no clue and i should email them but so far no answer

Comment: no it was simple procedure with OTP pin and no i didnt use my CRN

Comment: I would get a letter from your credit card issuer that your old card number was lost and replaced with the new card number.  The airline could still require you to purchase a new ticket if they feel any fraud might be involved.

Comment: Who's asking to see your credit card exactly? Sounds like a scam. Never in several hundreds of flights have I been asked to show my credit card of purchase. It is easily possible that the ticket can be booked by someone else, by an agent, as part of a group, etc... so that many cases exist that make it impossible to have the matching credit card with you.

Comment: @Itai it's common in countries with lots of credit card fraud, e.g. Thailand's airlines often ask for the card on domestic flights

Comment: @JonathanReez - And what happens if you don't have it? Or if you didn't book it? Or you booked for a group, who gets to show the credit card?

Comment: @Itai worst case scenario you pay for the same ticket again on-the-spot and the original payment is refunded. We have some questions on this site about this.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me for travel from North America to Southeast Asia  and back in 2015 using a VISA card. I don't know if your experience will be the same, but here is what I remember:

On the day of the flight when I checked in I had to fill out a form stating that the card with which I paid the original fare was no longer valid. I also had to give the number of my new VISA card to EVA Airlines. They were well versed with the process and there were no delays other than filling out the form.

Given your situation, I would still try to contact the airline to confirm the process you will need to go through (better safe than sorry). Also, you should have the old number of your credit card ready, just in case.

Comment: Just to add that this happens often - credit cards do expire before the trip starts so it is business as usual for airlines.

Comment: hey thanks a lot its a great help! i am still waiting for the response from the airline :) my card is lost is do i need to request for any kind of letter from my bank stating i lost the card ?

Comment: If your bank will give you such a letter for free (and it's not a big hassle for you) it won't hurt. Any evidence that the card is no longer valid that you can present easily to the airline will help. Have fun with final approach at Paro; last I read there are 8 pilots in the whole world who are qualified for it.

Comment: i will give it a try and call my bank thanks again . and about the 8 pilots thing i didnt even now ofr myself lol

Answer (score -1):

Not once in my history of travels was I asked to see the credit card that the plane ticket was paid this. I imagine I would not even able to show it at times, e.g. when travelling on tickets provided by my employer.

I've seen threats to check my CC, when booking non-plane tickets in Peru. I've also heard Deutsche Bahn requires to see the card for its train tickets. I find the requirement ridiculous, I mean, what about e.g. virtual cards? They have no physical shape.

Maybe in India it is an issue, you should probably specify the country more clearly in your question, because generally it's not an issue.

Comment: This is not correct, we have a lot of questions on the site which confirms this happens and yet all the time people question it because it's rare. For example http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81903/4188 http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/18019/4188 http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/83554/4188

Comment: flight is from delhi, india to paro , bhutan  it is mention on the guidlines that i should be able to show my credit card